# Correct place to call `std::default_random_engine generator`

Tags: c++

Need to generate a random permutation sequence for an array. For sure, we can use a STL function specifically designed for this purpose, but I want to do it manually as follows:

Question> Based on the code, it seems to me that we should NOT place `std::default_random_engine generator;` inside the loop. Is it true as a general rule?

```
// uniform_int_distribution
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <utility>

void test1() // random result
{  
  int p[10]={0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
  std::default_random_engine generator;
  for (int i=0; i<=9; ++i) {    
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(i,9);  
    int index = distribution(generator);
    std::swap(p[index], p[i]);
    std::cout << i << ": " << p[i] << std::endl;
  }
}

void test2() // NOT random
{  
  int p[10]={0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};  
  for (int i=0; i<=9; ++i) {    
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(i,9);  
    int index = distribution(generator);
    std::swap(p[index], p[i]);
    std::cout << i << ": " << p[i] << std::endl;
  }
}


int main()
{
    test1();
    std::cout << "*****************" << std::endl;
    test2();
    return 0;
}

/* output
0: 0
1: 2
2: 8
3: 6
4: 7
5: 3
6: 5
7: 9
8: 4
9: 1
*****************
0: 0
1: 1
2: 2
3: 3
4: 4
5: 5
6: 6
7: 7
8: 8
9: 9

*/
```

Answer (score 2):

The random generator engine gets seeded when it comes into scope.

In your first function, you have this basic structure:

```
void test1() // random result
{  
  std::default_random_engine generator;
  for (int i=0; i<=9; ++i) {    
      // ...
  }
}
```

That random number generator gets seeded when you enter `test1()`.  Every time you call `test1()` you'll get a fresh generator, and so likely the same permutation.  The scope of that generator is from its point of declaration to the closing brace of `test1()`.

In your second function, you have this alternate structure:

```
void test2() // NOT random
{  
  for (int i=0; i<=9; ++i) {    
    std::default_random_engine generator;

    // ...
  }
}
```

This generator comes into scope near the start of each iteration of the loop, and goes out of scope at the end of each iteration (just before the loop increment).  This will give you the same random number sequence on each iteration, I believe.

If you want one random sequence that gets seeded once, you need to have only one instance of the generator.  Either make it a global variable, or pass references to the generator as arguments to your functions.

Comment: Life was so much easier when all we had was `rand()` and `srand()`. They've been in use for forty years, and are well understood. But now that they're "Considered Harmful", I guess everyone has to figure out how to use the new facilities correctly.

Comment: @PeteBecker:  Judging by the number of questions I see here on SO where folks are calling `srand()` repeatedly, I wouldn't say they're well understood.  The bug above was roughly the same bug, only with the interesting (and welcome?) twist that even with this bug in place, other code in the same application wouldn't have seen its random number generators corrupted, if this was part of a large, complex application.

Comment: "Well understood" is not the same as "obvious to beginners". Many of the posts on SO that urge replacing `rand()` and `srand()` with "more modern" alternatives get the code wrong, causing lengthy discussions about how to do it right. Discussions of how to use `srand()` correctly are **much** shorter and simpler.

Comment: @PeteBecker: For some of these topics, it would be wonderful to have a well written, authoritative beginner's reference to point folks to.  You're right that the on-ramp for the C++ way is much more steep.  For anything that uses random numbers seriously, the new tools are much better once you do understand them.  But, random numbers are subtle creatures if you _really_ want to understand them.  Knuth wrote half a book volume on them!

Comment: I'm not arguing that the on-ramp is much too steep, just arguing against the knee-jerk reaction of replacing `rand()` and `srand()` with some flavor of C++11 random number generators whenever a question shows a problem using `rand()` and `srand()`. Most folks aren't far enough along the on-ramp to give good advice.

Comment: @PeteBecker : I'm actually irked at the "must do everything C++11" reflexes in general.  In my day job, I may not see a C++11 capable compiler for our embedded systems probably until some time in 2016 or 2017, and we're still trying to get some of our customers to take C++ _anything_ seriously.  (I say "embedded", but it's the kind of embedded with 12 processors 1+ GHz on one die and around 14MB of RAM with it.)

Comment: Sometimes SO reminds me of newsgroups twenty years ago, where if you mentioned Windows you were, ipso facto, in a state of sin, Unix being the one true way.